# "<someone> is waiting for you to respond to his friend request"

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

I'm rather new to Facebook and recently I've received a notification that I can't fully understand:

> `<someone>` is waiting for you to respond to his friend request

What does it mean?

I have some requests myself that are not accepted, and I can't see anywhere the option to "remind" the other person about this, and I can't figure out how `<person>` could have done this.

Is that something that you can do manually, or it is some kind of automated reminder?

The notification options says `Turn of notifications about friend_request_remind_async`.

I'm asking this because I want to understand more about this feature, it is the first time that I see something like that and I could not find much official information about it.

Here is the mandatory pic:

[image]

Comment: I'm asking this because I don't want to accept this request right now (it is only an acquaintance), but I also don't really want to offend this particular person by letting him know that I'm deliberately ignoring his request if he has manually "reminded" me.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this could be a new feature as well, since the notification is just an un-translated string, and it seems that there is not official documentation (yet?) available. But I'd like to hear more about this, if someone else could shed some more light.

Answer (score 1):

This is an automated message from Facebook. You've had a friend request "open" for some arbitrary time (determined by Facebook) and they're reminding you in case you've forgotten.

The person who sent the friend request is not getting similar notices, although they'll be able to see that the friend request is still pending if they go look at their outstanding friend requests.

Comment: So why am I not getting these notifications about *all* the friend requests I haven't answered?  Furthermore, many people I've sent friend requests to have left them pending for a long time, which is making me wonder if they're getting these nudge messages.

Comment: @Stewart: Maybe things have changed in the last couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

If someone had sent you friend request, you have option whether you accept or decline it. The request is still persisted until you decide.

Comment: Yes, but this is not was I was asking.